# UIButton's size is different to the enclosed UIImageView object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I put some view the `UIButton` object and set the image to the button using `setImage:forState:` method.
the image size is 19x8.
And, called `[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]` method to adjust Autolayout. The autolayout is only setting position of button.
then, I found out the button size is 19x22 and the enclosed image size is 19x8. The image position is center vertically.

Why the button is not same to the image?
How can I make them to same size?

---

I added the sample code.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFame:CGRectZero];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

That's it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed your button's constraints, the actual code for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to be of same size as the image then,first get the size of the image.

```
CGFloat width = myImage.size.width;
CGFloat height = myImage.size.height;

CGRect myRect = CGSizeMake:(myButton.frame.size.x,myButton.frame.size.y,width,height); //x and y with respect with superview.
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = myRect;
```

Comment: Hm... Unfortunately, I don't use to set the frame because using Autolayout.

Comment: Using autolayout your button's rect is changing according to device?

Comment: Check the edit, this code will change the button size to that of the image size, without changing its position